# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode' when sending a form through JS

Tags: javascript, python, django, image, fetch

I'm trying to send some data through a form using JavaScript Fetch to a Django view, including an image. I keep getting this error message nine times as if no data was sent to the back end:

[image: error message]

My view is as follows:

```
if "contributors" in data:
        try:
            Project.objects.get(title=data['title'])
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Project title already exists!'}, status=406)

        except Project.DoesNotExist:
            form = ProjectForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

            project = Project.objects.create(
                title=data['title'],
                description=data['description'], logo=data['logo'])

            return JsonResponse({"message": "Project successfully created!"}, status=201)
```

and my JavaScript:

```
  const projectName = document.getElementById("project_name");
  const contributors = document.getElementById("id_contributors");
  const description = document.getElementById("id_description");
  const logo = document.getElementById("id_logo");
  const projectCsrf = document.getElementsByName("csrfmiddlewaretoken")[0];

  document.getElementById("submitProjectForm").addEventListener("click", () => {

let formData = {
  title: projectName.value,
  contributors: contributors.value,
  description: description.value,
  logo: logo.files[0],
};

submitForm(projectCsrf, formData);
});

function submitForm(csrf, fields) {
const request = new Request(window.location.origin, {
  headers: {
    "X-CSRFToken": csrf.value,
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
  },
});

fetch(request, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(fields),
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((result) => alert(result.message ? result.message : result.error))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

is it maybe due to python's Json.loads method not being able to decode the JavaScript File object? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after hours of debugging I managed to figure it out. Ali javanmardi was partially right in that i should not have been converting the data to JSON because I was sending files.

The main issue for this error was in my headers in my fetch function:

```
"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
```

This appeared to be causing the main issue, when I changed this to:

```
"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
```

it worked.

I also converted all of the data collected from the form into FormData, rather than creating my own object:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("logo", logo.files[0]);
formData.append("title", projectName.value);
formData.append("contributors", contributors.value);
formData.append("description", description.value);
```

On the back end in my view, I should have been saving the form instance instead of creating a new Project object:

```
new_form = ProjectForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if new_form.is_valid():
                new_form.save()
```

Now I can upload images fine.

Answer (score 1):

As you are including an image in your data and your data is a formdata why you are converting it to a string:

```
fetch(request, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(fields),
})
```

I think you should add formdata itself to body of fetch api

```
fetch(request, {
  method: "POST",
  body: fields,
})
```